# Passing Arrays into an Array of Pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Please assist with below question on pointers to arrays. I have 20 arrays that are each 350 elements long. I need to pass the address of a select 3 out of the 20 arrays, to an array of pointers. 
Then later in my code I need to access individual elements within the arrays, within the array of pointers. However I am unsure as to the syntax, please comment as to whether the below is correct.

```
unsigned short      Graph1[350];
unsigned short      Graph2[350];
unsigned short      Graph3[350];
...       ...          ...
unsigned short      Graph19 [350];
unsigned short      Graph20 [350];
unsigned short      *ptr_Array[3];
...
*ptr_Array[0] = &Graph6;    // Passing the address of array Graph6, into the array of pointers.
*ptr_Array[1] = &Graph11;   // Passing the address of array Graph11, into the array of pointers.
*ptr_Array[2] = &Graph14;   // Passing the address of array Graph14, into the array of pointers.
...
Varriable1 = *ptr_Array[1]+55   // Trying to pass the 55th element of Graph11 into Varriable1.
```

Comment: Not an answer: `20 arrays that are each 350 elements` why don't you use 2-d array?

Comment: The array itself should be a pointer, isn't it?

Comment: @Rolice No array is not a pointer. It depletes to a pointer if used in expression or passed as argument to function.

Comment: Ah, thanks @MohitJain. I saw dereferencing and appeared strage to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `*ptr_Array[1]+55` is wrong multiple times, because of [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

The compiler sees it as `(*(ptr_Array[1]))+55`, that is it takes the second pointer in `ptr_Array` and dereferences it to get the first value, and add 55 to that value, which is not what you want. You need to explicitly use parentheses like `*(ptr_Array[1]+55)`. Or simply `ptr_Array[1][55]`.

---

And you should really consider the comment by Mohit Jain. Instead of having 20 different variables, just use one:

```
unsigned short Graph[20][350];
```

Answer (score 2):

`*ptr_Array[0] = &Graph6;` is wrong. It should be:

```
ptr_Array[0] = Graph6; /* or &Graph6[0] */
```

Type of `ptr_Array` is `array 3 of pointer to unsigned short`. `ptr_Array[0]` has type of `pointer to unsigned short` and `*ptr_Array` has type `unsigned short`.

Type of `Graph6` is `array 350 of unsigned short` which will **deplete** to `pointer to unsigned short` if used in an expression.

---

`Varriable1 = *ptr_Array[1]+55` is also wrong. To pass the 55<sup>th</sup> element, use

```
Varriable1 = ptr_Array[1][55];
```

Comment: One reason `&Graph6` is wrong is that the type of `&Graph6` is `unsigned short (*)[350]` (pointer to an array of 350 `unsigned short`), whereas each element of `ptr_Array` is meant to be an `unsigned short *`, and the two types are visibly quite different — which is why the compiler is complaining about pointer type mismatches.

Comment: `Varriable1 = *ptr_Array[1][55];` should be `Varriable1 = ptr_Array[1][55];`